# Change line plot color according to a feature

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have the following data frame.

| ID | Some Reading | Diagnosis | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | Stable condition | 1/2020 |
| 1 | 20 | Possible Failure | 3/2020 |
| 1 | 5 | Stable Condition | 5/2020 |
| 2 | 90 | Maintenance Required | 1/2020 |
| 2 | 150 | Imminent Fault | 3/2020 |
| 2 | 200 | Complete Failure | 4/2020 |

I wish to do a time series line plot of the 2 machines according the Some Reading factor. However, I wish to give them a different color based on the Diagnosis variable. For example, stable condition would be a greener shade, while Complete Failure would be black. How can I change a line's color like this?

This is the sort of thing I currently have, where each color is a machine:
[image: This is the sort of thing I currently have]

Comment: A line connects two points. What color should the line have that connects the data of the first two rows?

Comment: Possibly [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-multicolored-line-py).

Comment: @Mr. T Oh, good point, I didn't think this through